# Grid view event not getting triggered

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a gridview created dynamically , now i am trying to do edit each column by keeping a link button. But the rowdatabound event is not getting triggered.Where i might have gone wrong?
Below is my code :

```
dtValues = gObj.GetAllDocumentsHistoryList();
            dtHeader = gObj.GetAllHeaderList();
            GridView gvEmployee = new GridView();
            gvEmployee.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty = true;
            gvEmployee.EmptyDataText = "Sorry No History Records Found !!!!!!!";
            gvEmployee.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < dtValues.Columns.Count; i++)
            {

                string name = dtValues.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();

                BoundField boundfield = new BoundField();
                boundfield.DataField = dtValues.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();

                for (int j = 0; j < dtHeader.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (dtHeader.Rows[j]["ColCode"].ToString() == dtValues.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString())
                    {
                        boundfield.HeaderText = dtHeader.Rows[j]["ColName"].ToString();
                        if (boundfield.HeaderText.Contains("Date") || boundfield.HeaderText.Contains("DocExpiry"))
                        {
                            boundfield.DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}";
                        }
                    }
                    else if (dtValues.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString() == "Last Modified Date")
                    {
                        boundfield.HeaderText = "Last Modified Date";
                        boundfield.DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}";
                    }

                }

                gvEmployee.Columns.Add(boundfield);

            }

            gvEmployee.DataSource = dtValues;

            gvEmployee.DataBind();

            gvEmployee.Width = new Unit("90%");

            gvEmployee.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(gvEmployee_RowDataBound);

protected void gvEmployee_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton lnkView = new LinkButton();
            lnkView.ID = "lnkView";
            lnkView.Text = "View";
            lnkView.Click += ViewDetails;
            lnkView.CommandArgument = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row["Id"].ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(lnkView);
        }
```

Comment: are you using <updatepanel>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your RowDataBound handler before DataBind.

**Corrected Code:**

```
gvEmployee.DataSource = dtValues;

gvEmployee.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(gvEmployee_RowDataBound); 

gvEmployee.DataBind();

gvEmployee.Width = new Unit("90%");
```